# Is it possible to change the font of a parsed HTML in IText?

Tags: java, pdf, ckeditor, itext

First let me introduce the background around this problem:

I am using the [CKEditor](https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-5/) to implement some rich text fields in a project, the editor is included through javascript, and handle the fields creating a HTML which is properly rendered by the browser.

The challenge was to include tables generated by the editor on a PDF, I have tried with Jasper Reports but it didn't work very well (the parsed HTML did not render the tables and some styles generated by CKEditor).

I have tested the IText and it worked very well, I was able to parse the tables and almost all the styles of CKEditor throught the following code:

```
CSSResolver cssResolver = new StyleAttrCSSResolver();
CssFile cssFile = XMLWorkerHelper.getCSS(new FileInputStream(new File(CKEDITOR_CSS_FILE));
cssResolver.addCss(cssFile);

HtmlPipelineContext htmlContext = new HtmlPipelineContext(null);
htmlContext.setTagFactory(Tags.getHtmlTagProcessorFactory());

PdfWriterPipeline pdf = new PdfWriterPipeline(document, writer);
HtmlPipeline html = new HtmlPipeline(htmlContext, pdf);
CssResolverPipeline css = new CssResolverPipeline(cssResolver, html);

XMLWorker worker = new XMLWorker(css, true);
htmlParser = new XMLParser(worker);

// Parsing the HTML generated by the editor
htmlParser.parse(new FileInputStream(HTML));
```

It considers the CSS correctly during the parse and output the following table to me:

[image]

**My question is:** Is it possible to change the font of the parsed HTML to use for example, a smaller font or a bold font?

I will have a lot of fields that need to be included on the PDF, each field would be in a different section demanding different formatting. I was not able to find any interface to allow this customization on `XMLWorker`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed my approach and dropped the idea of incorporate the CKEditor CSS on my report.

Instead, I customized my own CSS for the HTML generated by CKEditor, at the end I have this structure:

1. A custom CSS for my report containing all the configuration and formatting:

```css
* {
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 20px;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

th, td {
  padding: 6px; 
}

table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

th {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

The result is this table:

[image]